# Применение события mousemove

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse-event, mousemove

На https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event к переменной myPics применяется событие mousemove, а мне необходимо, чтобы вместо myPics фигурировал скроллбар (т.е. курсор мыши остановился бы на скроллбаре) , если я правильно понял событие mousemove (подробности см. на [Получение координат курсора мыши после её передвижения. Обращение к скроллбару](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1315397/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%91-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%83)). Каким образом отследить момент, при котором курсор мыши переводится с левого бокового меню на скроллбар?

P.S. Создал новый вопрос, т.к. предыдущий стал довольно объемным. Прошу не минусовать, поскольку я новичок.

Comment: Скроллбар - это не DOM-элемент, на который вешают event, есть событие onscroll, при срабатывании которого выполняется код описанный в функции `element.onscroll = function () {ваш код}` либо же метод scroll - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll

Comment: @highpassion  а каким образом отследить момент, при котором курсор мыши переводится с левого бокового меню на скроллбар?

Comment: попробуйте, в ответе обновил код

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант с определением координат мыши за пределом документа:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    if( document.querySelector('body').offsetWidth <= e.offsetX ){
      console.log('GOTCHA!')//если мышь вышла за пределы body, то срабатывает код на этом месте
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Также вы можете попробовать сделать html-элемент, который с помощью js будет осуществлять прокрутку страницы (или другого элемента), а в CSS его поместить на место скроллбара задав абсолютное позиционирование, указав для этого элемента `position: absolute`, и свойства `top`, `right`, `left`, `bottom`, задать по длине всей страницы.